# Get Distinct Category Name From Class

Tags: c#

I  have a class with  following structure :-

```
  public class Gallery
{
         private string _category;
            public string Category
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return _category;
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        _category = value;
                    }
                }
        }
```

I created a list object like this :-  `List<Gallery> GalleryList = new List<Gallery>();`
I have added items to this list  object from sharepoint list. Now I need distinct category name from this list object. I tried  `GalleryList.Distinct()` . But I am getting error. Please help me if anyone knows the answer.

Comment: "I am getting error" doesn't give us any information...

Comment: please also state the error so others might have more chance in helping you.. - wow, hi Master Jon..

Comment: I tried '  List<string> DistinctCategory = GalleryList.Select(x => x.Category).Distinct().ToList(); ' and it isworking. Thanks.

Comment: I missed using system.Linq. That was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the category names, you need to project from the list of galleries to a sequence of category names - and *then* `Distinct` will work:

```
// Variable name changed to match C# conventions
List<Gallery> galleryList = ...;
IEnumerable<string> distinctCategories = galleryList.Select(x => x.Category)
                                                    .Distinct();
```

If you want a `List<string>`, just add a call to `ToList` at the end.

You'll need a `using` directive of:

```
using System.Linq;
```

as well.

Note that calling `galleryList.Distinct()` itself should compile (if you have the `using` directive) but it will just be comparing objects by reference as you haven't overridden `Equals`/`GetHashCode`.

If you actually need a collection of galleries, all of which have distinct categories, then you can use [MoreLINQ](http://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/1.0.16006) which has a `DistinctBy` method:

```
IEnumerable<Gallery> distinct = galleryList.DistinctBy(x => x.Category);
```

In that case you'd need a `using` directive for the `MoreLinq` namespace.

You should also learn about [automatically implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx). Your `Gallery` class can be written a lot more concisely as:

```
public class Gallery
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GalleryList.DistinctBy(x => x._category);
```

Comment: On its own, that won't compile - `DistinctBy` isn't part of LINQ. It's part of MoreLINQ and I dare say some other libraries, but you haven't mentioned anything like that.